# Where to find recent claims of CN204293650U

Tags: claims, china

Please let me know where I can find recent claims of patent application CN204293650U.

Answer (score 1):

The patent information about any Chinese patent is available at [SIPOpublicsearch](http://www.pss-system.gov.cn/sipopublicsearch/inportal/i18n.shtml)
to perform the search you need to register with the site then it allows you to search for patent information.

I found the following information most of which is in Chinese [image]